# Media query doesn't work at all

Tags: html, css, media-queries

After completing my whole website I was introduced to media queries as a way of making my website responsive. The thing is that even though I found many resources on Media queries and I know what to type they just don't work at all.

I first tried to test a media query in order to see how it works.
This is the code:

```
<style> 
@media screen and (min-width:600px){

#bigfont
{
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 79px;
    font-family: dosis, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
}
 </style>
```

"bigfont" is already a style in css. So when placing a media query it is supposed to bypass the original style and apply the new parameters.

Since my laptop screen's width  was larger than 600px I was expecting it to work but it didn't. My goal is to use media queries in order to scale up my content when it comes to a really big screen.

I even changed min to max just in case with no result.

UPDATE :
I forgot to mention that I already have this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Does this style block occur *after* your default `#bigfont` styles (Or are the default styles applied more specifically)?

Comment: Well I am not sure what you ask but the default bigfont style is the first thing you see as it is a welcoming message. For now it's still the same :/

Comment: @Ricky in the style block, do the media queries come before or after the rest of the styles?

Comment: oh I din't put it in the css file. As you can see there is a <style> that indicates that it's in html :)

Comment: but view port and media query is on the top of the code so they should work :/

Comment: Guys a little help on something related..  I want to use the media query to apply this ..  @media (max-width: 1400px) { zoom: 1.25; /* Old IE only */ -moz-transform: scale(1.25); -webkit-transform: scale(1.25); transform: scale(1.25); }   Think it's good ?

Comment: @George before posting a new question I would like to ask it here. 1. are media queries supported from most recent versions of browsers? 2. If I apply a media query in a link form in order to link the page with a new stylesheet will this conflict in any way with the current css style?

Comment: @Ricky 1) http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries, 2) It won't stop your current stylesheet being applied, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with `@media all and (min-width:600px){`? That usually fixed it for me.

If that does not work, try setting the values as `!important` (overwrites everything so far so you need to keep the `!important` part for larger screens, as you have `min-width`, and smaller if you have `max-width`).

```
    #bigfont
{
    font-size: 80px !important;
    line-height: 79px !important;
    font-family: dosis, sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 300 !important;
}
```

Comment: nope ... still the same. I tried both your suggestions :/

Comment: ooopsss.. yeap it worked :) I type too fast ... and there were too @media when trying your suggestions :)

Comment: Glad it worked. Have fun with responsive ;)
If you need more help don't hesitate.

Comment: You can test it out first, depends on your websites and elements. It shouldn't affect much of your layout, but that depends also on how your elements are positioned. Basically it's like zooming in on a smartphone, don't know if very useful.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. I am not sure if the syntax is right. I want to use it for big screens. For example... if the screen is a really big screen then zoom in to 120% eg.1.20  .  :/

Comment: Yeah, you need an element inside. You can add either 'body', or like this
@media (max-width: 1400px) {  * { zoom: 1.25; /* Old IE only */ -moz-transform: scale(1.25); -webkit-transform: scale(1.25); transform: scale(1.25); }}
The star means all elements

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `viewport` meta element to the `head` of your HTML page(s) for media queries to take effect. E.g.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: The next thing to check is specificity. If the @media rule comes before the other declarations for that element, or if they have higher specificity, they will win out.

Answer (score 0):

Mine only worked after I put the media query block after the original code.

So like this:

```
Main code{
    .whatever{
    }
    #whatever{
    }
}
@mediaquery{
    .whatever{
     }
    #whatever {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put !important tag i.e 'font-size: 80px !important;' to apply the new parameters